.razor file vs .cs file IsNullOrEmpty() usage differences
In a .cs file, you can call IsNullOrEmpty() directly on a string without any issue (StringVariable.IsNullOrEmpty()). However, in a .razor file, you have to write String.IsNullOrEmpty(StringVariable) in order to call the function. What is the cause of this difference? Why isn't it standardized, considering both are in c# and the babies of Microsoft?

To my knowledge, there isn't a built-in IsNullOrEmpty extension-method on String in the BCL, it's likely your project (or another project or assembly you're referencing and have had its namespace imported via a using statement) has one such method defined. And the reason your Razor .cshtml files don't have it in-scope is because you don't have a using TheNameSpace; in your _ViewImports.cshtml file.

In Visual Studio, right click on the two methods and go to their definitions.  Are they the same?

No, they're different functions, but both file types use c#, right? So why wouldn't they have the same base functions?

@FrasherGray: Because most of the functionality is in libraries, not a core part of the language itself.  If different libraries are being referenced in these contexts then different functionality is available.  Perhaps the code in the .cs file is including (with a using directive) an assembly which the Razor code is not.  Going to the method definitions will tell you what classes and assemblies define those methods.

Oh, I see. It appears in one file a different library (that happened to have String.IsNullOrEmpty() as a part of it) was imported, whereas in the other Visual Studio imported a library which had a function (IsNullOrEmpty()) that could be called off strings directly. That's odd; I'm used to functions for built-in data types being consistent. Thanks for the help!

Variable.IsNullOrEmpty() is not built into the language. Often many developers will implement it as an extension method  (example) you may have tripped and fallen into one of situations where its included in a dependency and you have access to it.
 public static class StringExtensions {
   public bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string mystring) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(mystring);
 }


Don't forget [MaybeNullWhen(true)] on mystring.

that's not required afaik, that's just a compiler directive.

Not required, no - but it means call-sites will get a C# nullable warning, e.g. String? thisIsNull = null; if( x.IsNullOrEmpty() ) { ... } will get a warning. But not if you change it to ( [NotNullWhen(true)] this String? myString) or ( [MaybeNullWhen(false)] this String myString ).
